# Create new column based on conditions of other 2 columns Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that was concatenated and has two identical columns with two different names.

It looks like this:

```
Fuel Category     Gen MW    Gen MWh  Time Stamp        Time Zone
Dual Fuel         2809.0    nan      12/09/2015 00:05   EST
Hydro             2224.0    nan      12/09/2015 00:05   EST
Natural Gas       nan       150.00   12/09/2016 00:05   EST
Nuclear           4787.0    nan      12/09/2015 00:05   EST
Other Fossil      nan       20.0     12/09/2016 00:05   EST
```

The problem was that one header was called `Gen MWh` and the other `Gen MW` for different time periods. I just want to take a new column and fill it where `df['Gen New MW']` = `df[Gen MW]` when `df['Gen MWh']='nan'` and = `df[Gen MWh]` when `df['Gen MW']='nan'`.

I've tried:

```
for i in range(0, len(df)):
    if df['Gen MW'].iloc[i] == 'nan':
        df['Generation (MW)'].iloc[i] == df['Gen MWh'].iloc[i]

    elif df['Gen MWh'].iloc[i] == 'nan':
        df['Generation (MW)'].iloc[i] == df['Gen MW'].iloc[i]
```

But this iterates through and produces nothing.

Is there a way I can easily do this?

Comment: I feel like this is a recurring question.

Answer (score 2):

Use combine_first or fillna as @piRsquared suggested,

```
df['Gen New MW'] = df['Gen MW'].combine_first(df['Gen MWh'])

df['Gen New MW']

0    2809.0
1    2224.0
2     150.0
3    4787.0
4      20.0
```

Option 2:

```
df['Gen New MW'] = df['Gen MW'].fillna(df['Gen MWh'])
```

Comment: or `df['Gen MW'].fillna(df['Gen MWh'])`

Comment: @piRSquared, Long time!

Comment: o/ Yeah, been busy (-: